# Swift Array of objects filtering

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I've the following array of objects which I'm trying to filter and return for a searchDosplayController.

```
var family = [Family]()// fetchedFamily
var filteredFamily: [Family]! // filter fetched events
```

And that is how, I'm filtering it:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text

        self.filteredProvince = provinces
                if !searchText.isEmpty {
                    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
                    let array = (filteredProvince as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
                    filteredProvince = array as! [Province]
}
```

However nothing is getting returned when I'm searching. And I tried to do it in this way:

```
filteredFamily = searchText.isEmpty ? family : family.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
           return dataString.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
        })
```

But, I'm receiving the following error: 'Family is not a subtype of String'. Is there any better way to filter the Family? Because, the filtered result has to be sent back to searchDisplayController.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So we have a `Family` class that does look like this right?

```
class Family {
    let name : String
    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Then we have a list of `families`:

```
var families = [Family]()
```

And we want to extract all the families where the `name` property contains a given text.

```
let searchText = "something here"
```

Good, first of all we add this extension to the `String struct`.

```
extension String {
    func contains(find: String) -> Bool {
        return self.rangeOfString(find) != nil
    }
}
```

And finally we can filter the families writing:

```
let filtered = families.filter { $0.name.contains(searchText) }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the attempt but didn't work. The family class is an object of the coredata

Comment: When searching in the searchDisplayController, only one result got displayed over and over